# How decrypt data from Blazor.SubtleCrypto?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, cryptography, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm using the Blazor.SubtleCrypto library for data encryption on the frontend. It works fine. Unfortunately, this library does not work on the backend (asp.net webapi). How can I decrypt data from this library on the backend side?

Comment: Just to check, why would you want this when you already connect over  https ?

Comment: Unfortunately - this is my non-functional requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Blazor.SubtleCrypto uses JSInterop for the execution of the decrypt function which it calls via Dependency injection.

It is technically meant to run on the browser thread. As per the author of the nuget package the package does not support any other projects other than WASM and Blazor server:

Message from author:
[image: Message from author]